# How to get the location provider name in iOS?

Tags: ios, location

In Android whenever you get location object you could call "location.[getProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProvider%28java.lang.String%29)" on the instance to get value like "wifi". Is there something similar in iOS (CLLocation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9) says:

> The [CoreLocation] framework uses information obtained from the built-in cellular, Wi-Fi, or GPS hardware to triangulate a location fix for the device. It reports that location to your code and, depending on how you configure the service, also provides periodic updates as it receives new or improved data

Having said that, you do not have access to how precisely the `CLLocationManager` determined your location (other than, if you used significant change, that it probably used cell towers). You theoretically could use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to see if you have Wi-Fi availability, but you have no assurances as to what mix of GPS, cellular, and Wi-Fi it used to get your location (even if you happen to have WiFi connection).

What you do have is [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy), which tells you approximately how accurate the location you received is. From a user's perspective, that's probably a more important piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a concept of what system provided you with the location on iOS. What you can do is check what the accuracy of the location is. Based on how precise the location is, you can probably surmise if the location was provided by a GPS signal.

The reason this isn't given is that iOS will provide you with an initial location which won't be very accurate (likely based on geo-ip or cell triangulation) and then update the location with more and more precise coordinates if GPS is available.

If your application *requires* the accuracy provided by a GPS chip, you can add `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities = gps` to your Info.plist.